# How to handle merge conflicts with Subversion on Mac?

Tags: mac, svn, xcode

We are developing a Xcode project, using subversion version control.

I have yet to find a good tool to handle merge conflicts. Any tool recommendations? What you are using?

At the moment I am using Kdiff3, but it is a lot of work to handle lots of conflicts. Ideally I'd like to have graphical interactive tool.

Update: I found SmartSVN product, and I think it is the best.

Answer (score 2):

FileMerge.app (can be configured to run from scripts / command-line as opendiff).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html) under linux and apparently there's a mac port available.  Also a quick Google search found [DiffMerge](http://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) which looks promising (though I've never used it.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm in love with [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/). I find it the simple and intuitive UI, along with simplistic keyboard shortcuts saves lots of time compared to the command line or other programs.